# Server Rewrite for lowercase from uppercase issue

Tags: .htaccess, server, url-rewriting, uppercase, lowercase

My hosting company is telling me: On our platform the folder names are case sensitive. Unfortunately, it is not possible to access the folder name test using TEST and vice versa.

My issue is: if a url request "www.domain.null/TEST/" is entered and the folder has a lowercase like "www.domain.null/test/ - it is not possible for a htaccess rewrite to change the request to lowercase correctly, is this an accurate statement?

Is this an issue with my host or ALL hosting companies? DO i need to do a redirect for ALL uppercase possibilities to the lowercase urls for my site?

Thank You

Comment: will post after uploaded to server.

Comment: Croises, I enter the code below in one root folder in the public.html_folder which contain a few websites - and it worked fine, then I added it to another website root folder and it did not work - the result was a white page, and on the third a white page - but it still worked in the original website. I removed from the first & it stopped working - thinking that it may only work for one website because of something unknown to me in the PHP and server coding - Can you advise why it works on in one website root folder.? I left it in the website that needed - will it work - perhaps a cache issue?